# Android MapView ItemizedOverlay Draw onTap

Tags: android, canvas, android-mapview, itemizedoverlay, touch-event

I am trying to draw a custom shape in Draw method of ItemizedOverlay. Is it possible to get onTap event for the shape drawn. 
Currently onTap works for default drawable/marker. How to make it work for the shape drawn in Draw method?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can override 
the hittest method from itemized overlay.

Replace the method with a test to see if you hit your shape.
Please post your solution here for others afterwards.

Here is the original android version

```
    protected boolean hitTest(OverlayItem item, Drawable marker, int hitX, int hitY) {
            Point eventPos = new Point(hitX, hitY);
            Point itemHitPosOnDisplay = calculateItemPostionRelativeToDisplay(item.getPoint());
            Point distance = Point.substract(eventPos, itemHitPosOnDisplay);
            if (marker == null) {
                    marker = this.defaultMarker;
            }
            if (Math.abs(distance.x) < marker.getIntrinsicWidth() / 2
                            && Math.abs(distance.y) < marker.getIntrinsicHeight() / 2) {
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
    }
```

Regards,
 Stéphane

Comment: Yes this works for default marker, but not for the drawing on canvas.

Comment: let me rephrase it, can I make the canvas drawing as default marker?

Comment: I don't know if you understood what I proposed. But did you *override* the method I mentionned ? What did you try ?